# Sage accounting software tag as opposed to sagemath

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

I am reviewing suggested Edits this morning and came across one where the editor has removed the [sage](/questions/tagged/sage) tag from this question: [Sage Accpac Ireport method failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501903/sage-accpac-ireport-method-failed)

They left this note:

> sage tag only is for sage math software (sagemath.org). To whoever moderates this - what would a good tag for the accounting software be? Clearly one is needed, this happens about once a week.

I personally don't know anything about either piece of software so I figured I would pass along their question here to bring more attention to the matter.

**EDIT:**

P.S. props go to [kcrisman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782821/kcrisman) for bringing this issue up.

**EDIT2:**

More information about the 2 different software that [sage](/questions/tagged/sage) may refer to:

- Sage ERP AccPac or Sage 300 ERP: http://na.sage.com/sage-300-erp/
- SageMath: http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: This could use disambiguation; our company uses Sage products too and I wouldn't have thought of sagemath upon seeing the tag 'sage'

Comment: I thing `sagemath` and `sage-erp` would be good disambiguation.

Comment: Just as an FYI, there continue to be a problem like this every month or so.  How do things like this get resolved?

Comment: @kcrisman You pointed to this post to justify [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3257731), but I don't see any conclusive answer.

Comment: @Gray -  You are correct.  I don't really have authority to make up lots of new tags.  But the current tag description itself is pretty clear.  See my suggestion below - I don't know how to migrate all current `sage` tags to `sagemath`, nor which of the possible `sage-accounting` etc should be used for that product.  Do you have a suggestion of how to  resolve this?  Trust me, I don't edit these tags because it's fun, I do it because I think it's necessary to avoid ambiguity for people searching for help on either product on stackoverflow.

Comment: I definitely don't mean to imply that you have anything other than good intentions. I was just a little thrown off by the seemingly circular justification for the edit. I edited that question to have a `sage-erp` tag because it seemed appropriate. In the future, if you see a mis-categorized sage tag, then you can use that one. I suppose if it turns out to be wrong, then it can be fixed somewhat easily as long as they are categorized somewhat. I am just making suggestions here because I have neither the authority or knowledge to make this decision. I think it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264005/how-to-deprecate-a-tag for a followup.

Comment: Alternative proposition and accompanying suggestions in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363386) to @kcrisman's [follow-up question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302971).

Answer (score 2):

I like @nhahtdh's answer, and suggest upgrading it to have

- `sagemath` for Sage math
- `sage-accounting` for the whole suite of Sage accounting software
- `sagepay` already exists for the UK online payment version of the Sage accounting software, apparently
- `sage` would then be a disallowed tag somehow, if that's possible.

As long as all current `sage` tags are migrated to the proper new tag, I think this would be acceptable to those of us who answer Sage (math) questions.  I don't think that there is a Sage accounting answering community in the same way ;-)

Comment: Here's [yet another question which has this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478682/sage-line-50-odbc-driver-download-locations).  The sage.com folks have a _lot_ of products, so it would be hard to know how many different tags to have...

Comment: Now that Sage math is SageMath (see http://www.sagemath.org/) this answer makes even more sense.  How could one implement it?  I don't have enough rep to suggest synonyms or certainly to retire a tag (though `sage` definitely is just too ambiguous at this point).